# If loop in jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to add a class to a tag using jquery based on a if condition 
the code is

```
  if ($(".asp:contains('Home')")) {
    $("ul.nav-pills a:contains('Home')").
    parent().addClass('active');
}
else if ($(".asp:contains('List')")) {
    $("ul.nav-pills a:contains('List')").
    parent().addClass('active');
}
```

am i doing it right?

Comment: Where is your `html` code then?

Comment: Wether or not you're doing it right depends on what the heck you are doing, and what you're expecting ?

Comment: `if ($(".asp:contains('Home')"))` is always evaluated as `true`, you need to check for `length`: `if ($(".asp:contains('Home')").length)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$()` returns a jQuery object, **always**. jQuery objects are not falsey. If you want to see if anything matched, use either `.length` or `[0]`

So:

```
if ($(".asp:contains('Home')")[0]) {
    $("ul.nav-pills a:contains('Home')").parent().addClass('active');
}
else if ($(".asp:contains('List')")[0]) {
    $("ul.nav-pills a:contains('List')").
    parent().addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of [0]?

Comment: @JatinAsija: The way I'm using it above, it effectively checks to see if the jQuery object is empty -- e.g., the selector didn't match anything. You can index into a jQuery object the way you can an array; if there's an entry at that index, you get the raw entry (e.g., DOM element). And as with an array, if you look up an entry that isn't there, you get the value `undefined`, which is falsey, whereas non-`null` object references are truthy. So `blah[0]` looks up the entry at index 0, and `if (blah[0])` will go into the body of the `if` if there's an entry there.